# the ring of integers: prove that (2) is a prime ideal and that it is a pid

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integer-rings

Consider a real root $\alpha$ of $f(X)=X^3-3X+1$. Consider the ring of integers $A_K$ for $K=\mathbf{Q}[\alpha]$. I showed that the ideal $(1+\alpha)$ is prime in $A_K$ and that $A_K=\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]+(\alpha +1)A_K$. It is clear that the discriminant of $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ is $3^4$. How can I prove that $A_K=\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$ and that the ideal $(2)$ is prime in $A_K$ and $A_K$ is a PID?
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: $f(X-1)$ is Eisenstein at $3$, and $f$ is irreducible modulo $2$. Then use Minkowski bounds.

Comment: Thanks @franzlemmermeyer for the precious hints! Can you give me some suggestions to prove the equality $A_K=\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$ be Eisenstein at $p$
(all $a_j$ are integers divisible by $p$ and $p^2 \nmid a_0$) and let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$. Then $p$ does not divide the index of $\alpha$, that is, if
$$ \xi = \frac{r_1 + r_2 \alpha + \ldots +r_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}}p $$
is an algebraic integer, then $p$ divides all the $r_j$. The proof is simple:
$\xi \alpha$ is an algebraic integer, but $\alpha^n$ is divisible by $p$,
hence 
$$ \xi_1 = \frac{r_1 \alpha + \ldots +r_{n-2}\alpha^{n-2}}p $$
is an algebraic integer. Repeating this step the claim follows.

In your case, $f(X-1) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3$ is Eisenstein at $3$, and since
the discriminant of this polynomial is a power of $3$, we find that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ must be an integral basis.

Comment: Thank you for the proof. Do you think that it is correct the following way: I know that $A_K 0\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]+(\alpha+1)A_K$ and that $3^m A_K \subset \mathbf{Z}[\alpha] \subset A_K$, so $A_K=\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]+(\alpha +1)A_K \subset \mathbf{Z}[\alpha]+3A_K \subset \mathbf{Z}[\alpha]+\mathbf{Z}[\alpha]\subset \mathbf{Z}[\alpha]$? Thanks